# regular expression behaving weird in django urls

Tags: regex, django, python-2.7

Here is regular expression in urls.py

```
url(r'^company_data/(?:[A-Za-z]+)/((?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?:20)?[0-9]{2})*/((?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?:20)?[0-9]{2})*$', 'stats.views.second', name='home'),
```

my views.py

```
def second(request,comp_name,offset_min,offset_max=None):
```

I am calling in this way from browser `/company_data/hello/24092014/25092014`

Expecting in the below way

```
comp_name= "hello", offset_min="24092014",offset_max="25092014"
```

In reality it is

```
comp_name="24092014",offset_max="25092014"
```

What wrong did I do here??
Thanks in advance!!
    enter code here

Comment: It has solved Mistake is (?:[A-Za-z]+) have to use ((?:[A-Za-z]+))

Comment: No: just leave out the ?: altogether, since that explicitly marks a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a capture group 1.

*Edit:* Also note that groups 2 and 3 should be done like below, unless I'm reading you
wrong and you intend to retrieve the last part of particular number groups.

```
 # '^/?company_data/([A-Za-z]+)/((?:(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?:20)?[0-9]{2})*)/((?:(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?:20)?[0-9]{2})*)$'


 ^ 
 /? company_data /
 ( [A-Za-z]+ )                                   # (1)
 /
 (                                               # (2 start)
      (?:

           (?: 0? [1-9] | [12] [0-9] | 3 [01] )
           (?: 0? [1-9] | 1 [012] )
           (?: 20 )?
           [0-9]{2} 
      )*
 )                                               # (2 end)
 /
 (                                               # (3 start)
      (?:

           (?: 0? [1-9] | [12] [0-9] | 3 [01] )
           (?: 0? [1-9] | 1 [012] )
           (?: 20 )?
           [0-9]{2} 
      )*
 )                                               # (3 end)
 $
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 37 ) 
/company_data/hello/24092014/25092014  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 14 , len 5 ) 
hello  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 20 , len 8 ) 
24092014  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 29 , len 8 ) 
25092014
```